# Undo all jquery when back button pressed

Tags: jquery, function, undo

I have a page where if you click on certain items it removes other items. I was wondering whether it is possible to when the back button is pressed it removes all functions that have taken place other than `$(document).ready(function(){` which is what I use to start jquery.
I tried:

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function() {
    var hash = location.hash.substring(1);
    if($('.container1').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('.container').show();
    } else if($('.container1').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('.container').show();
    }
});
```

Though that didn't work

Here is a fiddle of the deleting of the elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/fuwJy/

Comment: Do you mean that you want a click on the browser's back button to stay on the current page but reset it to the way it was when it first loaded? As if the user had clicked the browser's refresh button?

Comment: Please be clear and specific.

Comment: I am using `href='#'` so it can go back to the previous page but all of the jquery needs to be set back to how it was

Comment: There is no easy way of doing that, nothing i'm aware of

Comment: I thought that it was hard. Have you seen what I have tried?

Comment: An easy way could be to reset the body but i'm quite sure this is not what you are looking for

Comment: How would I do that? if it works, i'm fine with it

Comment: It depends what you are looking for. If you could provide a jsfiddle with minimal relevant code and logic you are using, i could have a look at it.

Comment: @roasted added fiddle

Comment: I don't understand what you are calling going back. Here you are just using anchor tag for internal link (href #). BTW, except click handler, there is nothing to clean.

Comment: I have a link that has a href of # when you click it certain items disappear I used a href so that when it went back it would show the others so that it would look like a totally different page